# Corona sdk : Play sound when Object is in a specified area

Tags: audio, coronasdk

I would like to play this sound

```
audio.play(colsound)
```

when my ball passes through an obstacle (there is a free space between obst1 and obst2)

```
ball = display.newImage("ball.png")
    ball.x = 100; ball.y = 100
    physics.addBody(ball, "dynamic", {density=.05, bounce=0.1, friction=.2, radius=12})
    screenGroup:insert(ball)
    ball.myName = "ball"

    ----
    obst1 = display.newImage("obst1.png")
    obst1.x = 640; obst1.y = -500
    obst1.speed = 3
    physics.addBody(obst1, "static", {friction=0.5, bounce=0.3, density=.1 })
    screenGroup:insert(obst1)
    obst1.myName = "obst1"


    obst2 = display.newImage("obst2.png")
    obst2.x = 640; obst2.y = 500
    obst2.speed = 3
    physics.addBody(obst2, "static", {friction=0.5, bounce=0.3, density=.1 })
    screenGroup:insert(obst2)
    obst2.myName = "obst2"
```

( just like in flappy bird when the bird passes through the tubes, a sound pop out ... ).

and here is the code that I'm using to detect collision and play sound, the thing the object that I'm putting between Obst1 and Obst2 keep the ball from passing through ( should I set the velocity to 0 or set physics.setContinuous( false ) )

```
function onCollision (event)

    if (event.object1.myName == "obst1") or (event.object1.myName == "obst2") then 
    storyboard.gotoScene("restart", "fade", 400)
    audio.stop()

    end

    if (event.object1.myName == "obst3") then 
    audio.play(colsound)  

    end
    if (event.object1.myName == "t") then  --the transparent object
    audio.play(colsound, 1) 
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

place the one physics object in middle of the two obstacle and find collision to play the audio.

Comment: I've done that, but when the object collide with the other it keeps it from passing through, I've added some transparent bare but on the one hand it keeps it from passing through (tunnelling), and on the other hand it change my ball (main object) x and y and the object start flying around ....